# Consecutive Print to target same output Cell

Tags: performance-tuning, front-end, cells, output, printing

Is it possible to conveniently direct the output of consecutive **Print** statements to the same output **without actually accumulating the output in a temporary string/variable**?

This would be useful in cases where there are a lot of small outputs say like in the example below:

```
For[i=1,i<=1000,i++,
Print[i," "];
]
```

By default each of the Print statements produces a new output cell, which is not desirable. I would prefer a C-style dump-to-terminal output, where one just prints i with a space.

Comment: Something like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30741/5478) or you want to affect only Print?

Comment: What about `PrintTemporary`?

Comment: Related: ["How to print without having newline added automatically at the end?"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4602/280)

Comment: Tangentially related: ["Is it possible to Print expressions in reverse order?"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4129/280)

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov : Thanks for the links. The key takeaway is **WriteString["stdout",..**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++, WriteString["stdout", i, " "];]
```

Comment: What is the easiest way to get the the output to line wrap to window width?

Comment: Simple and clean. Exactly What I was looking for!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You could either change the Stylesheet or, the hard way, do: `For[i=1,
If[i===1,(CurrentValue[#,PageWidth]=WindowWidth)&/@Cells[CellStyle->"Print"]];
i<=1000,i++,WriteString["stdout",i," "];]`

Comment: Well I don't have `Cells` in v7.  How would I use the style sheets?  Could it be done without affecting anything else (only the custom print function)?

Comment: You have to change the Print style: set PageWidth->WindowWidth. I forgot how to do this at the notebook level. But you could create a custom stylesheet I guess. I gave up on style sheets a long time ago and just use the default one.

Answer (score 3):

I would manipulate the front end as the code is being run from the front end

```
For[i = 1, i <= 1000, i++, Print[i, " "];];
SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], Next, CellGroup];
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["CellMerge"]]
```

Try the above code. I am at a loss as to what you will do next with the merged cell.

Comment: This can simplified a hair by replacing `FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["CellMerge"]]` with `FrontEndTokenExecute["CellMerge"]`.

Comment: @Hans : I have a long-running calculation on a comp which is "unstable" - So i need it to save the outputs peridodically (AutoSave -> True) and want the output to be as compact as possible (which is why I did not want the newline to be automatically added). Thanks for your solution. I could use it in some other case! :)