# How do I insert a calculated value into a text cell?

Tags: string-manipulation, formatting

Suppose in a notebook I've calculated the value of some expression and assigned it to a variable. How do I insert the value of that variable in a text cell without just typing in the value? That is, I want Mathematica to insert the value.

So something like:

```
f[x_] := x^3+x^2+1

The value of this function at 7 is N[f[7]].
```

Should be displayed in the notebook as:

```
f[x_] := x^3+x^2+1

The value of this function at 7 is 393.
```

Comment: In the text cell enter the variable name, highlight it, and use the menu command `Evaluation | Evaluate in Place`

Comment: Related: "[Is there a way to accelerate buffering to the screen](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65242/280)."

Comment: If only we could Evaluate in Place a Dynamic[something] in the middle of a text cell...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(to complement the other answers, further into the automation side)

You can actually create a dynamic text cell, so that the value gets dynamically updated, while still being able to edit the content of the text cell (lets say, the "string"). Not to be confused with a dynamic output, having some text in it. This can be done in different ways.

**First method:**

- start by creating two dynamic cells: `Dynamic[a]` and `Dynamic[f[a]]`
- then, create a text cell (e.g. `Alt+7`), where you write: "The value of this function at {copy here the output of the `Dynamic[a]`, by simple copy-paste} is {copy here the output of the `Dynamic[f[a]]`, by simple copy-paste}".
- now, you can set the variable `a` to whatever you want, that the text cell will update itself, while still being a completely viable/editable text cell

**Second method:**

This alternative shows how to do the above in a more "automatic" way:

- `CellPrint[{TextCell[Row[{"The value of this function at ", Dynamic[a], " is ", Dynamic[f[a]], "."}],{"Text"}]}]`

And you can be much more flexible, if you just create a pointer for each `Dynamic`:

- `CellPrint[{TextCell[Row[{"The value of this function at ", Dynamic[a], " is ", Dynamic[b], "."}],{"Text"}]}]`
- `a=7;`
- `b:=f[a]`

**Following some discussion with WRI Support:**

You can actually *Evaluate in Place* `Dynamic` content (I mean, you just write `Dynamic[a]` wherever you want, and then select it, and from the context menu you *Evaluate in Place*). Although, when you do it, it doesn't look like it has worked, this is because the *Evaluate in Place* returns an `InputForm` (something that, due to the current architecture of the *Front End*, might not change in the near future). So, to have the *Evaluate in Place* return what most of us would expect from expressions like `Dynamic[...]`, `Graphics[...]`, etc. one must force the `StandardForm` (for instance, by preceding the code with `StandardForm@...`

**And, going even further...**

One can create a generic dynamic element, that can be copied as many times as needed (by simple copy-paste, or introduced through a custom palette button, etc.), and that will either show its evaluated form, or, upon click, its unevaluated form/code, ready to be edited, as an `InputField`. Here's a very rustic example of this idea:

```
DynamicModule[{showInput = False, code}, 
 Dynamic[
  If[showInput == False, 
   EventHandler[Dynamic[ToExpression@code], {"MouseClicked" :> (showInput = True)}], 
   InputField[Dynamic[code, {(code = #) &, (showInput = False) &}], String]]
 ]
]
```

[image]

(Null is the copy-paste part of the above code output, that will actually be, the first time you run, a FE`code$$...)

A more advanced example based on the idea of having an editable code field is given on Edmund's answer (although not expressed as a text cell) and on his answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103072/78). Some limitations to this `InputField` based techniques may exits, if you are using CDF Player, since, for obvious reasons, it has `InputField` coding limitations.

**And NEW in Version 10: `TextGrid`**

`TextGrid` allows you to create an output that can be edited directly, without losing its formatting. Interesting enough, you can either add `Dynamic` content into the grid cells, at the creation moment, and then, still have the possibility of editing the text of the output; or you can use Evaluate in Place of `StandardForm@Dynamic` expressions contained or edited into the text strings.

Answer (score 7):

```
f[x_] := x^3 + x^2 + 1

Row[{"The value of this function at ", 7 , " is ", f[7], "."}]
```

[image]

Or

```
StringTemplate["The value of this function at `1` is `2`."][7,  f[7]]
```

Comment: Both the `Row` and the `StringTemplate` expressions produce text within Output cells rather than, as the OP requested, within Text cells.

Answer (score 7):

```
f[x_] := x^3 + x^2 + 1
```

1. Create a text cell containing:

   $\qquad$The value of this function at 7 is N[f[7]]
2. Select N[f[7]] in the cell
3. Choose Evaluate in Place from the Evaluation menu or that operation's keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> on OS X)

Answer (score 6):

To create an actual text cell, as opposed to an output cell containing text, use

```
f[x_] := x^3 + x^2 + 1 
CellPrint[{TextCell[Row[{"The value of this function at ", 7, " is ", f[7], "."}],
    {"Text"}]}]

(* The value of this function at 7 is 393. *)
```

[image]

Comment: That answer produces text within an Output cell rather than, as the OP requested, within a Text cell.

Comment: @murray  How did you arrive it this conclusion?

Comment: sorry, I was wrong about this: *definitely* the `CellPrint[{TextCell`... expression *does* produce a `Text` cell, just as requested by the O.P.

Comment: @murray  No problem.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Your example with f[x] can be achieved without the lower-level cell functions by using `Mouseover` and `Dynamic`.

```
f[x_] := x^3 + x^2 + 1

Row[{
  "The value of ",
  HoldForm[f[x]], 
  " for x = ",
  Mouseover[Dynamic@x, 
   InputField[Dynamic@x, Expression, FieldSize -> 2]], 
  " is ", 
  Dynamic@f[x]}]
```

With this method you only need to input the value of `x` as any expression (no `N` function needed) and it will provide your result.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: That answer produces text within an Output cell rather than, as the OP requested, within a Text cell

Answer (score 2):

```
"The value of this function at 7 is "<>ToString[N[f[7]]]<>"."
```

If you want to remove double dot at the end cast result to Integer:

```
"The value of this function at 7 is "<>ToString[Floor[f[7]]]<>"."
```

Comment: That answer produces text within an Output cell rather than, as the OP requested, within a Text cell