# Saving data from a long computation when Mathematica does not respond

Tags: crash

I ran some a somewhat long computation with Mathematica during 5 days (on my University's computer, which is not very powerful), and Mathematica could not display it as it was too long. So I thought to print it, but did not use the function 'Print', which made the program crash a few hours ago (e.g. I have no access any more to the functionalities of the program). Rather than closing the program and loosing all data, I wanted to know if there was any way to salvage it while Mathematica was still running.

Comment: Related: "[Is there a way to accelerate buffering to the screen?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65242/280)"

Comment: You can append intermediate results of the computation to a file (but of course you should implement this beforehand).

Comment: Since there are no answers, I think you may add an **Update** section with the clarification.

Comment: I deleted my comment as I had not regained control in fact, just opened by mistake another instance of the file which misleaded me into believing it was working again...