# How to put the evaluated result in a text cell?

Tags: cells, output

If I use the function `Print`, the result is not in a **text cell**. So I wonder If there's a function that I can use to *put behind the function `Print`*, to make the evaluated result be placed in a **text cell**?

[image]

Here's the testing code!

```
1 + x^2 + x^4 /. x^p_ -> f[p] // Print
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 2):

```
CellPrint[TextCell[1 + x^2 + x^4 /. x^p_ -> f[p], "Text"]]
```

Comment: Cool, thanks, bravo

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to print into *plain text* cells, you have the following possibilities:

1. Instead of `Print`ing into usual `StandardForm` `Cell` where the parsing and 2D formatting take significant processor's time you can print into *plain text* `Cell`s:

   ```
   CellPrint[Cell["stuff=" <> ToString[stuff]]]
   ```

   Upon printing, you can assign the usual `"Print"`, `"Text"`, `"Output"` or another style to such a cell without changing its rendering from *plain text*:

   ```
   CellPrint[Cell["stuff=" <> ToString[stuff], "Text"]]
   ```

   The *plain text* rendering is determined by the fact that the `Cell[...]` object contains a simple `String` as the first argument and not a `BoxData` object.
2. Instead of printing into separate cells you can append the output into the same *plain text* `Cell` as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30793/280):

   ```
   stuff := RandomReal[];
   Do[WriteString["stdout", "stuff=" <> ToString[stuff], "\n"], {10}]
   ```

   This works extremely fast.

   Here `"stdout"` is the name of the standard output stream. You can get the corresponding stream object with `Streams["stdout"]`. The standard output channel is [`$Output`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%24Output.html), which by default sends everything to `"stdout"`. You can read more about them in [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FilesStreamsAndExternalOperations.html#21617) tutorial.

Comment: Your answer is really informative, which is more than what I expected, really instructive!

Comment: `WriteString[channel,expr1,expr2]`, so the "stdout" means the channel? Actually, I don't know what is channel. Can you give some words about it?

Comment: @Lawrence `"stdout"` is the name for the standard output stream. You can get the corresponding stream object with `Streams["stdout"]`. The standard output channel is [`$Output`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Output.html), which by default sends everything to `"stdout"`.

Comment: @Lawrence You can read more about them in [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FilesStreamsAndExternalOperations.html#21617) tutorial.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks bro